# Como crear el equivalente de Cell_array de Matlab en Python

Tags: python, matlab

Tengo este código en Matlab que estoy intentando pasar a Python (soy nuevo en este lenguaje):

```matlab
fid = fopen('database/database.txt');

db_cell = {};
i = 1;

while ~feof(fid)
    line_ex = fgetl(fid);
    ima = imread(line_ex);
    ima = im2double(ima);
    db_cell{1,i,1} = ima;
    i = i+1;
end
```

No se me ocurre mejor forma para guardar un conjunto de imágenes RGB que el formato cell, pero no sé cómo crearlo en Python, o algo similar. También tengo problemas con el tema de leer hasta fin de fichero... en Matlab sería como arriba, pero para Python he visto el leer línea por línea mediante:

```py
f = open("demofile.txt", "r")
for x in f:
  print(x)
```

Puedo utilizar esto para sustituir a fgetl de Matlab? 
Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Como crear el equivalente de cell_array de matlab en Python

Comment: Hola Alberto, bienvenido! :-) Has considerado llamar MATLAB desde Python?. Te paso un link por si te es de utilidad: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html?refresh=true

Comment: Hola, Maria, gracias por tu ayuda. Me sirvió.

Comment: Me alegro mucho! :-D Si encontraste la solución, porque no publicas la respuesta tú mismo? Así quien llegue la podrá usar y de paso ganarás algo de reputación :-) Un abrazo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He pensado que ya que se está usando Python y no Matlab es por algo, entonces he aquí como hacer algo equivalente:

```
def lectura_db(route):

    fid = open(route, "r")
    names = []
    content = []

    for x in fid:
        """Separamos la cadena en trozos según el carácter '/', ya que es una ruta, y nos quedamos con la última, que es en sí el nombre de la imagen con el carácter de fin de cadena, que posteriormente eliminamos."""

        ruta_ima = x.split("\n"[0])
        ima = split_string(x, "/")
        ima = ima[-1]
        # Eliminar el \n de cada línea leída
        ima = ima[:-1]
        names.append(ima)

        imagen = io.imread(ruta_ima[0])
        # imagen = img_as_float64(imagen)
        ima_norm = norm(imagen)
        content.append(ima_norm)
        # content.append(imagen)

    fid.close()

    return names, content
```

En vez de devolver una única variable con todo, devuelves por un lado los nombres de las imágenes, y por otro lado cada una, de tal forma que cuando quieras acceder sea más cómodo así.